# foreach with await method

Tags: c#, async-await

This code checks 2 clients connected with a socket for which one pushes a button first, the connection and receiving works fine but if I click the button of the client that is second in the deelnemersTimer and clients dictionary it doesn't do anything, it will just keep waiting till I click the one first in the dictionary. I'm pretty sure it's the await in the foreach that is wrong but what do I need to change to get this working correctly?

clients is a dictionary with client names and their socket.
deelnemersTimers is a dictionary with client names and the time they clicked the button.
Also deelnemer is dutch for participant.

```
foreach (Deelnemer deelnemer in deelnemers)
{
    deelnemersTimer[deelnemer.DeelnemerVoornaam + " " + deelnemer.DeelnemerNaam] = await CheckButtons(clients[deelnemer.DeelnemerVoornaam + " " + deelnemer.DeelnemerNaam]);
}
deelnemersTimer.Values.Min();
var eerste = deelnemersTimer.Where(p => p.Value == deelnemersTimer.Values.Min()).Select(p => p.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

```
private async Task<long> CheckButtons(StreamSocket socket)
{
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

    var actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(1);
    long time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return time;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe in detail what should the code do? Should the result be returned as soon as the first participant presses the button? What should happen to the sockets of other participants?

Comment: When the participants click a button the checkbuttons returns an elapsed time, this time is filled in the deelnemersTimer and it checks which one was first. The problem is that when the second client clicks first the foreach is still waiting for the first one to click and then when I click the the first one the times are mixed up for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating another method which would set `deelnemersTimer` and `eerste` and then calling that method without `await`ing (at least not immediately):

```
private Task ProcessButton(Deelnemer deelnemer)
{
   string id = deelnemer.DeelnemerVoornaam + " " + deelnemer.DeelnemerNaam;
   deelnemersTimer[id] = await CheckButtons(clients[id]);

   // is this the first one?
   if (eerste == null)
       eerste = id;
}

…

var tasks = deelnemers.Select(ProcessButton);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

(This assumes both `deelnemersTimer` and `eerste` are fields.)

This way, you start processing for each button at the same time and set the results as they complete.

Comment: Weird, `deelnemersTimer` gets set perfect but when I click the button on the first client and it exits `ProcessButton`, I get a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: @maarten1055 Where exactly do you get that exception? I don't see anything in my code that could throw that (assuming `clients` is set up properly), so there might be something else going on.

Comment: When `ProcessButton`is done and it goes back to `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing exactly what you told it to do: for each connection, (asynchronously) wait for a button click on that connection.

If you want to listen for a button click on *all* connections simultaneously, you can do something like this:

```
var buttonTasks = deelnemers.Select(deelnemer => CheckButtons(clients[deelnemer.DeelnemerVoornaam + " " + deelnemer.DeelnemerNaam]));
var buttonsClicked = await Task.WhenAll(buttonTasks);
```

Comment: How does this change anything? The original code finished only after all buttons were pressed and your code behaves the same way. Though it's not very clear to me what is the code actually supposed to do.

Comment: It starts all the `CheckButtons` simultaneously, so each method invocation can complete individually. The difference is that the stopwatch values will be correct. It's my guess for what the code was supposed to do. :)